# ignore empty list when plotting histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a stacked histogram in Python, with something like the following command:

```
pylab.hist([data1,data2,data3], 10, normed=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
```

But sometimes the lists data1/2/3 are empty and this creates an error. Is it possible for Python to ignore any lists that are empty when plotting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension which filters out empty lists and pass the result to the histogram creator:

```
pylab.hist([x for x in [data1,data2,data3] if len(x) > 0], 10, normed=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
```